# Oracle SQL : Weeks back from a Date in Join

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

I have a table with transactions over several years that has the week of the year number column (1-53) added as well. I want to join the table back to itself and summarize for each year/week combination , rows that are back 12 weeks from the year/week. For example, if I have 2018 week 15 I want to summarize weeks 5-14 from 2018.

I cant just look at the difference between week numbers because of the multiple years.

Is there a function or method to allow this join criteria?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Is week 53 a full week (every few years or so)?  Or might it just be one or two days?

Comment: Which [week numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) system does your week number use?

Comment: So your table has a year column and a week column and no date column? And you want to aggregate your data so as to get a result list of `week | sum_for_week | sum_for_previous_10_weeks`? And is there one row per year and week in the table or multiple rows?

Answer (score 1):

*I suppose such a mechanism below where your `log` table and `connect by level <= 53` joined together may help :*

```
  with log_mytable( transaction_time ) as
  (
   select timestamp'2019-04-08 14:53:23' from dual union all
   select timestamp'2018-04-04 08:25:16' from dual union all
   select timestamp'2018-04-03 12:11:05' from dual union all
   select timestamp'2018-03-03 18:05:06' from dual union all
   select timestamp'2018-03-03 17:15:46' from dual union all 
   select timestamp'2018-03-03 14:05:36' from dual union all 
   select timestamp'2018-02-06 23:05:42' from dual union all 
   select timestamp'2018-01-15 03:24:31' from dual union all 
   select timestamp'2018-01-01 00:15:27' from dual
  ), t as 
   (
   select to_char(transaction_time,'yyyyiw') as transaction_time, 
          substr('&i_week',-2)- lvl + 1 as flag, -- '&i_week' = 201814 whenever prompted
          max(to_char(transaction_time,'yyyyiw')) over (order by lvl desc) 
                                             as max_transaction_time
     from log_mytable   
     right join ( select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 53 )
       on lvl = substr(to_char(transaction_time,'yyyyiw'),-2) 
      and to_char(transaction_time,'yyyyiw') <= '&i_week'      
   ) 
  select max_transaction_time - flag + 1 as "Week", 
         count(t.transaction_time) as "Count" 
    from t 
   where flag between 1 and 12
   group by max_transaction_time - flag + 1
   order by "Week" desc;

   Week     Count
   201814   2
   201813   0
   201812   0
   201811   0
   201810   0
   201809   3
   201808   0
   201807   0
   201806   1
   201805   0
   201804   0
   201803   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure how your columns are defined, but I had a go at your problem.

```
with data(year, week, value) as(
SELECT 2018  year
     , Level week
     , 1     value
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 53
union all
SELECT 2017  year
     , Level week
     , 1     value
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 53
) 
select 'Sum values 12 weeks before ' || :year ||' '||:week, sum(value) from data
where 1=1
and (year = :year 
and week < :week
and week >= :week -12)
or ( year =:year -1
and week >= case when :week -12 <=0 then (:week -12 + 53) end)
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to research the connect by to understand what it is doing, I am not familiar with its usage.

Comment: it is just a way to get a lot of test data. try to run just the following by itself: SELECT 2017  year
     , Level week
     , 1     value
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 53